# Attribute in C# winforms to specify resource selector?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, attributes, embedded-resource

I made a custom control for WinForms in C#. One of it's properties is an audio stream that will be played at some point. Is there a way I can tell VS that this property should be chosen from the resource manifest (specifically audio resources) with a property or similar?

[image: The property, defined.]

The commented property is an audio stream.

[image: Control properties.]

This is how it shows in the WinForms designer.

[image: Binary data editor.]

This is what you get when you click the edit [...] button. I want this to be replaced by an [audio] resource chooser.

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't understood you question:
- Are you looking for a built-in (ready) designer for this?
- Do you want the editor to be capable to choose and import an audio file beyond those already listed in project resources?
- Why both answers given doesn't fit your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyAudioEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)]
```

This attribute let you specify a specific editor to be used when that property is displayed in a property grid.

You can then derive and create your new editor from a base type. The base type must be or must derive from System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor.

In most case, when the Editor is invoked, you pop-up a form of your choice, and bind its return value to your property.

UITypeEditor has 4 virtual methods and one virtual property that let you change all the behavior when someone interact with your property or when your property is painted in the grid.

Comment: You're getting at there being no default type that lets the control's user select any project or form resource? That being the case, you shall have the best answer, though I knew about this option prior.

Comment: Nevermind, I am just surprised that VS doesn't have a default form for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @watkinsj: Ah! Yes, it is weird, but it's not very hard to implement one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a code below that shows how I would do it myself.

Just some observations:

- In my code, I created a String property `AudioName` which will be set in the designer. This property refers to the resource name in your assembly. The `Audio` (read-only) property of type Stream you are interested in, will then be retrieved from the chosen resource name.
- As Marc-André Jutras pointed in his answer, you'll need to code your own `UITypeEditor` or `TypeConverter` to retrieve the Audio resources from your assembly. I've chosen in this case to implement a custom `TypeConverter`.

  ```
  Public Class Form1
      <System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(GetType(AudioConverter)), System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("(none)")>
      Public Property AudioName As String

      <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)> 'This will make the property not appear in the designer
      Public ReadOnly Property Audio As Stream
          Get
              If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AudioName) OrElse
                  AudioName = "(none)" Then
                  Return Nothing
              End If
              Try
                  Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(AudioName)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  Return Nothing
              End Try
          End Get
      End Property
  End Class

  Public Class AudioConverter
      Inherits System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter

      Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesSupported(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
          Return True
      End Function

      ' Set the property to be informed only from predefined (standard) values
      Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesExclusive(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
          Return True
      End Function

      ' Get possible values that will be inserted in the drop-down list
      Public Overrides Function GetStandardValues(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext) As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection

          Dim returnList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
          returnList.Add("(none)")
          For Each resItem As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, True, False)
              Dim resourceEntry As String = resItem.Key
              If TypeOf resourceEntry Is String Then
                  returnList.Add(resourceEntry)
              End If
          Next

          Return New System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection(returnList)
      End Function
  End Class
  ```

Comment: Love the code sample, but this seems to defeat the purpose (being tied into VS' resource manager).